# How to move from one view controller to another with an Action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

IM not Using Storyboard.

Ive place a button, on my PlayViewController and when tapped I want the user to go back to the Main menu which is the ViewController.

When I add this line of code:

```
- (IBAction)backToMenu:(id)sender {

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It dismisses the ViewController - I want it to present it, So I used:

```
  ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I get this ERROR: "Receiver 'ViewController' for class is a forward declaration"

I need to present my main menu, how am i supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the target view controller in your PlayViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```